# If I were to factory reset my device, would my kernel be reverted to my default one?

Tags: kernel

Would my kernel be reset to its default variant? If not, is the only way to factory reset my kernel to flash the default one?

Comment: See almost same Q&As here: https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A96277+factory+reset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, factory resetting your device does not revert the kernel.  Yes, if you want to reset your kernel you must flash it.